# Python Error in my_thread_global_end(): xxx threads didn't exit

Tags: python, multithreading

getting this error.
On linux 64bit with python 2.7

```
 Error in my_thread_global_end(): xxx threads didn't exit
```

tried at end of code but nothing about open threads. closed
all connections...

```
 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Some quick googling suggests it's a problem with a MySQL library, but it's usually associated with PHP rather than Python. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25621

Comment: @RB, I saw that. is there away to kill threads?